# Is it safe to remove "proposed" from sources.list?

Tags: apt, updates

I just realized that one of my production machines has :

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

enabled inside its apt-get `sources.list`.  luckily this is just a cloud based load balancer..

is it safe to remove this line from `sources.list`? if a "beta" (or "proposed" update) is overwritten by a stable release in the future, does anybody see potential issues that could arise in such a scenario?

if all I face is a potential "downgrade" to a stable release, this is not a problem.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to remove the `-proposed` pocket.

By default, `apt` won't downgrade your packages. However, when there is a newer version in any other pocket/repo, `apt` will upgrade the package to that version.

<s>As it is, `-proposed` has a lower priority than the other pockets (`-proposed` has a priority of 400, while most other things have a priority of 500), so I believe you would have to explicitly request a package from this pocket for `-apt` to use this pocket.</s>

EDIT: The `-proposed` pocket is **not** by default a lesser priority than the other pockets (see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) on setting it as a lower priority). Therefore, if you enabled `-proposed`, your packages will be from this pocket.

Comment: soo.. in response to your edit; I likely have some proposed updates installed.. but they will eventually be superseded by a stable version (the next time one is released)?

Comment: Yes. My guess is that more critical components (like the kernel) will move into the stable pocket within a few days (so you'll have what everyone else has).

Comment: luckily this is a cloud based load balancer, running OpenVZ. since the kernel is independent of the OS... I am just concerned about Mission Critical Applications breaking. anyways, thanks for your response